# Hide Site Guest User When Assigning Users

Tags: permissions, profile, force.com-sites, relationships, guest-user

We recently created a two public sites, where we've enabled apex classes. The only purpose of these sites are to update a record field when called. The Apex classes have `@RestResource(urlMapping='/<my-site>')` set, and each site has a `@HttpPost` method.

The user making changes to the records, are a Guest User - which is fine.
The problem is that now, when assigning unrelated records/objects to other users, the two guest users are visible on the dropdown menu.

My question is: Is it possible to *hide* guest users from being shown in dropdown menus across Salesforce?

Thanks

Comment: Are you saying that the Change Owner button, when clicked, exposes the guest users?

Comment: Yes - that is the behaviour we're seeing.

Comment: see Help doc on [guest user record ownership](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_guest_record_default_owner_best_practices.htm&type=5) - in general, this is not recommended and instead you should use sharing sets

Comment: How would that ensure that guest users can't be seen/chosen during a 'User Lookup' ??

Comment: In my org, that does not allow guest users to own recs, no guest user appears in User lookup